# Forma correcta de usar el operador alignas con new y delete C++

Tags: c++

estoy tratando de usar un buffer dinámico uint8_t creado con el operador new, el propósito es usarlo para guardar objetos de tipo personalizado y que se puedan crear y destruir a voluntad en el mismo trozo de memoria, esto es para evitar llamadas repetidas a new y delete.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//clase de ejemplo
class miTipo{
public:
    int a;
    char b;

    miTipo (){
    std::cout << "creado" << std::endl;
    }
    ~miTipo(){
      std::cout << "destruido" << std::endl;
    }
    void usar_objeto(){
        std::cout << "objeto funciona bien" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    int cantidad = 100; //cien objetos
    uint8_t* buffer = new alignas(miTipo) uint8_t[sizeof(miTipo)*cantidad];

    int posicion = 0; //posicion 0 para crear el objeto
    miTipo* objeto_1 = reinterpret_cast<miTipo*>(buffer+posicion*sizeof(miTipo));
    
    //llamamos al constructor
    std::construct_at(objeto_1);
    
    //usamos el objeto, vida util
    objeto_1->usar_objeto();
    
    //destruimos el objeto, memoria disponible
    std::destroy_at(objeto_1);
    
    //liberamos el buffer al final del programa 
    //delete[]  buffer;

}
```

salida:

```
creado
objeto funciona bien
destruido
```

El problema que me tiene atascado es la alineación. He colocado el operador `alignas(miTipo)` donde el compilador no se quejó, no se a donde va realmente y el operador delete sino me funcionó cuando le puse el alignas.

```
delete[] alignas(miTipo) buffer;
alignas(miTipo) delete[] buffer;
```

Probé diferentes combinaciones pero ninguno funcionó

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta resumida sería, `alignas` no se usa con el operador `delete`.

Cuando tu haces una reserva de memoria de tamaño X, al liberar la memoria se verá afectada **la totalidad** de la reserva. No podrás elegir si deseas liberar solo una parte del principio, del final... o incluso del medio. Si reservas X bytes de una vez, al liberar la memoria, se liberarán exactamente esos X bytes.

Por otro lado, no estás usando `alignas` de forma adecuada. Según su propia [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), solo debe usarse al declarar tipos:

> The alignas specifier may be applied to:
>
> - the declaration or definition of a class/struct/union or enumeration;
> - the declaration of a non-bitfield class data member;
> - the declaration of a variable, except that it cannot be applied to the following:
>
>   - a function parameter;
>   - the exception parameter of a catch clause.

En cualquier caso no hay que olvidar que, en condiciones generales, el uso de `alignas` es totalmente innecesario. Esto es así porque el compilador ya realiza una alineación nativa de los datos.

Especificar una alineación explícitamente únicamente sirve para garantizar una separación adicional entre los datos. Por ejemplo, si estás creando objetos de menos de 32 bytes, puede que te interese forzar una alineación de 32 bytes (aún desperdiciando memoria), para optimizar el rendimiento de la caché.

```
Sin alineación
| 32 bits            | 32 bits            | 32 bits            |
| objeto | objeto | objeto | objeto | objeto | objeto | objeto |

Con alineación
| 32 bits            | 32 bits            | 32 bits            |
| objeto |  -libre-  | objeto |  -libre-  | objeto |  -libre-  |
```

Este no es tu caso, ya que supuestamente intentas forzar una alineación igual al tamaño del objeto, es decir, estarías intentando aplicar la alineación por defecto, que es la que ya se estaría aplicando sin necesidad de hacer absolutamente nada.